# Number of concatenations

Tags: list

I am not sure the problem is correct for SO. Eventually, I will migrate it.

Please consider a list `[1; 2; ..; n]`. How many ways there are such that it can be expressed as a concatenation of two lists?

The answer that I gave to this is `n + 1`. The problem with my answer, is that it is based only on empirical observation.

I.e. given a list of length `3` such as `[1; 2; 3]`, I think that I can represent it as:

```
[] @ [1; 2; 3]
[1] @ [2; 3;]
[1; 2] @ [3]
[1; 2; 3] @ []
```

Is my hypothesis correct? How do you suggest to test it on a stronger basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this from the construction of lists:

A list is either the empty list `[]` or a pair `(a, L)` where `a` is an element and `L` is a list.

Formally

```
L := []
    |  (a, L)
```

Now, to define your number of concatenations:

```
ncat(L) := 1 if L=[]
            ncat(M)+1 if L=(a, M)
```

Both cases are easy to see. There is no other way to concatenate two lists to an empty list except for `[]=cat([], [])`. And by construction,  `L = cat([a], M)`, hence exactly one additional way to split `L` compared to however many splits are in`M` already (i.e. after the `a`).

Note  that the specialty of being able to concatenate the empty list either at the head or tail of another list is safely included in this proof, left to the diligent reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this by induction.
You show that your formula holds for `n = 1` (or `n = 0` if you want to consider the epsilon case)

then you show that your formula holds when going from n to n = n + 1.

It then follows that it is correct for all n.